# Windows Phone 8 Development: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, user-controls, dependency-properties

I'm using usercontrol in windows phone development.  The custom control has a property: `ButtonsCountProperty`

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonsCountProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ButtonsCount", 
            typeof(int), typeof(WCCSegmentControl), 
            new PropertyMetadata(0, new PropertyChangedCallback(ButtonsCountChanged)));
```

In the callback method `ButtonsCountChanged`, I write:

```
button.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(segmentcontrolButtonClick);
```

The error occurred.

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property
```

Anybody know how to write the button click event in the PropertyChangedCallback static method?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I know the solution.
I create an instance of the current class:

```
public static WCCSegmentControl _wccSegmentControl;
```

And I add this to the static method:

```
button.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(_wccSegmentControl.segmentcontrolButtonClick);
```

It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

because ButtonsCountChanged is a static method, you need to cast to the owner object

```
private static void ButtonsCountChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
    WCCSegmentControl control = (WCCSegmentControl)d;
    control.button.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(segmentcontrolButtonClick);
   }
```